# Building mod_nss for Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I need to compile mod_nss for Apache 2.4.27 on SLES 11 SP 4 since it's the only option to enable TLS 1.2 right now for me. I know using legacy OS is a pain, so it's a temporary solution just because SLES 11 doesn't support OpenSSL 1.X, so I can't use mod_ssl as usual.

What I have:

- Apache 2.4.27 (installed from sources to /opt/apache2)
- Apache source code located in /tmp/apache2_build/httpd-2.4.27
- Mod_nss source code: https://releases.pagure.org/mod_nss/
- OS: SLES 11 SP 4
- Installed from packages prerequisites (mozilla-nss-devel-3.47.1-38.12.1, mozilla-nspr-devel-4.23-29.9.1)

What I was doing:

```
cd <mod_nss_sourcecode_dir>
autoreconf -ivf
./configure --with-apxs=/opt/apache2/bin/apxs
gmake all install
```

The last command returns the following output:

```
gmake  all-am
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/apache2_build/httpd-2.4.27/modules/mod_nss-mod_nss1018'
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/opt/apache2/include -I/usr/include/nspr4   -I/usr/include/nss3 -I/usr/include/nspr4    -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/nspr4    -g -O2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DENABLE_CHACHA20 -DENABLE_SERVER_DHE -DNSS_SUPPORTS_TLS_1_3 -MT mod_nss.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mod_nss.Tpo -c -o mod_nss.lo mod_nss.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/opt/apache2/include -I/usr/include/nspr4 -I/usr/include/nss3 -I/usr/include/nspr4 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/nspr4 -g -O2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DENABLE_CHACHA20 -DENABLE_SERVER_DHE -DNSS_SUPPORTS_TLS_1_3 -MT mod_nss.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mod_nss.Tpo -c mod_nss.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mod_nss.o
In file included from /opt/apache2/include/httpd.h:44,
                 from mod_nss.h:20,
                 from mod_nss.c:16:
/opt/apache2/include/ap_config.h:136:16: error: os.h: No such file or directory
In file included from mod_nss.c:16:
mod_nss.h:28:21: error: mod_ssl.h: No such file or directory
mod_nss.c:253: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
mod_nss.c:254: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
mod_nss.c: In function ‘nss_proxy_enable’:
mod_nss.c:310: error: ‘othermod_proxy_enable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:310: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
mod_nss.c:310: error: for each function it appears in.)
mod_nss.c:313: error: implicit declaration of function ‘othermod_proxy_enable’
mod_nss.c: In function ‘nss_engine_disable’:
mod_nss.c:339: error: ‘othermod_engine_disable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:340: error: implicit declaration of function ‘othermod_engine_disable’
mod_nss.c: In function ‘nss_register_hooks’:
mod_nss.c:588: error: ‘othermod_proxy_enable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:588: error: ‘apr_OFN_ssl_proxy_enable_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:588: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
mod_nss.c:589: error: ‘othermod_engine_disable’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:589: error: ‘apr_OFN_ssl_engine_disable_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_nss.c:589: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
mod_nss.c:595: error: ‘apu__opt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
gmake[1]: *** [mod_nss.lo] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/apache2_build/httpd-2.4.27/modules/mod_nss-mod_nss1018'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Previously I had errors related to absence of **os.h** and I fixed them by creating a symlink from apache source dir to apache installation in /opt:
[/opt/apache2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKnul.png)
What can I do to fix this? I was trying to add path to "/tmp/apache2_build/" dir using **--include=** parameter

Comment: In my case "include" directory was absent in /opt/apache2. After running "make install" from Apache source, those directories were restored and the compilation process became easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_nss.h DOES include mod_ssl.h, so you need to put in an included path.

You can find it in the modules/ssl directory of the Apache source.